# How to make pipe run sequentially

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

#### Specs

Don't think this should make a difference but I'll include it anyway

GNU bash, version 3.2.51

---

#### Premise

So say i have a pipe with multiple parts, how can I prevent part of the pipe running before the previous part is finished.

---

#### Example

In the below examples I will try to display the issue

```
$ echo hello | tee /dev/tty | (echo "Next";sed 's/h/m/' )
```

Output

```
Next
hello
mello
```

With sleep to show that it is the timing that is off

```
$ echo hello | tee /dev/tty | (sleep 2;echo "Next";sed 's/h/m/' )
```

Output

```
hello
Next
mello
```

---

#### Expected Output

Is as above

```
hello
Next
mello
```

but obviously this depends on the sleep being longer than it takes for the previous command to finish which is not what i would want.

---

#### Notes

I know there are better ways to do this but I just think it would be educational for me to understand exactly how the pipe is working.

---

#### Tried

Tried variations of wait and sleep and things but nothing works consistently.

---

[l0b0's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32135646/4923629)

This still prints Next first though

```
$ echo hello | tee /dev/tty | sort |(echo "Next";sed 's/h/m/' )
Next
hello
mello

$ echo hello | tee /dev/tty | tac | tac |(echo "Next";sed 's/h/m/' )
Next
hello
mello
```

If any more information is needed then please let me know.

Comment: using `()` creates another pipeline within the next and sed, which is generally why you end up with the Next being printed as you consider, out of order. If you replace it with a brace expression `{}` then the `tac | tac` manipulation (you can use `sponge` singularly if you have it) should work as expected.

Comment: @Petesh `as you consider, out of order`, no need to be condescending, it clearly is out of order. Also if i use curly brackets, then it hangs/ waits for input. Also what you are saying makes no sense anyway as the sed is still executed after even though it's in the `another pipeline`(subshell not pipeline there is no pipe).

Comment: Not meant to sound condescending; that was not my intention. The syntax for `{}` is a bit more rigid - You have to have spaces to the left and right of the brace, and a trailing `;` for the commands e.g. `{ echo "Next"; sed 's/h/m'; }`. I've just noticed that it doesn't work on another system I tried. If you're trying to sequence the echo and sed, you need a trailing `| tac | tac`, though.

Comment: @Petesh Yes i left off the trailing `;`,thanks. But after trying it now it still prints `NEXT` first. Also surely just using `cat` instead of `tac | tac` would have to same effect as it waits for input, or would it not ?

Comment: The intent was to force sequence points around the thing that may be able to run asynchronously, so what you end up with is something like: `echo hello | tee /dev/tty | cat | ( echo "Next"; sed 's/h/m/' ) | cat`.

Comment: The only issue with using `cat` on it's own is that it only buffers a small amount, while `tac | tac` buffers everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no language construct in `bash` to modify the behavior of a pipeline like you want. However, you can use a named pipe to act as a type of binary semaphore:

```
mkfifo block
echo hello | 
  { tee /dev/tty; echo go > block; }  |
  (read < block; echo "Next"; sed 's/h/m/' )
```

The `read` command blocks until something writes to named pipe, which does't happen until `tee` completes.

(Note that this may not *completely* solve your problem, as in addition to the process synchronization you may need to contend with the fact that you have multiple processes writing to the same output file, and you don't have complete control over how the various writes are multiplexed (due to buffering, etc.)

Comment: If the echoed-in text is bigger than the buffer size of the pipe, this code will block, because tee cannot push its output into a full pipe.

Answer (score 8):

The point of a pipe is to process data asynchronously, so as to save time and space overall. If you want to have a synchronous pipe you might as well write to file (on a RAM disk if you need the speed). But for tasks where the receiving commands are able to handle data in chunks the complete pipeline may be much slower:

1. `a | b | c` can at best be as fast as the slowest of the three commands.
2. `a > file; b < file > file2; c < file2` can at best be as fast as the **sum** of the runtimes of each command.

So if the commands all run in about N seconds (when run separately), you're looking at a best case runtime of N for the first command and 3N for the second command.

Comment: Yep I knew they ran asynchronously, but was wondering if there was a way of tellling a command in a later part of a pipe that the one in the first part is finished before starting. I also already know there are better ways (using files) as I mentioned in the question. How do commands know to wait when they are recieving data from  a previous pipe . For example the second sed will always execute after the data has been through `tee` ?

Comment: Your new suggestion doesn't work, I'll update my question

Answer (score 1):

The reverse twice trick works as expected: for obvious reasons, `tac(1)` needs to consume the entire input before writing the results to output, so using `tac | tac` ensures that the next command in the pipeline does not start reading input before the previous command finishes. Note that I said *does not start reading input*, rather than *does not start executing*. This is very important as you will see.

The problem here is that you are invoking a subshell where the first command does not depend on input being available. `echo(1)` doesn't block waiting for input, so this is essentially a race condition: the subshell process races with the `tee(1)` command to see who writes first to the terminal. Pipes provide synchronization based on input availability, if there is some process in the pipeline that does work without depending on input availability, that process will necessarily race with other processes in the pipeline; you can't prevent that.

To fix it, you need to somehow print `Next` only when the shell has available input in the pipeline. A quick hack is to do it with another `sed(1)` command that replaces the start of each line with `Next\n`:

```
echo hello | tee /dev/tty | tac | tac | ( sed -e 's/^/Next\n/' | sed 's/h/m/' )
```

This works, but the semantics are not exactly the same: now, the string `Next\n` is part of the input to `sed 's/h/m/'`. This isn't a problem in this example, because `Next\n` has no occurrences of the letter `h`, but take into account that this hack changes the input stream - this may or may not be a problem for your specific use case.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Your solution is more of a work around for this specific example than a solution to the problem as a whole. I really want to somehow block on non blocking commands until they receive input from the previous pipe. Actually you've just given me an idea, thanks! I'll report back in a minute.

Comment: @User112638726 *I really want to somehow block on non blocking commands until they receive input from the previous pipe.* You generally can't do this unless the command reads from the pipe. So you will always need some hack / workaround to consume input, so that you can leverage the synchronization capabilities of pipes. Can you show the specific example where this answer didn't work?

Comment: I don't have a specific example, I was just wondering if there was a generic solution. I just wanted to know if it was possible but judging by the replies here it is not(without a hack). I appreciate the answer though.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can force a stream to be read in completion by using `cat` and storing the result in a variable:

```
$ echo hello | tee /dev/tty | ( echo before; x="$(cat)"; echo after; sed s/h/m <<<"$x" )
before
hello
after
mello
```

Comment: This was the best answer for my purposes (doesn't need `tac`), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work and doesn't require a named pipe.

```
$ echo hello | tee >(tac|(echo "Next";sed 's/h/m/')) | cat
hello
Next
mello
```

I avoid /dev/tty as it isn't always available (like SSH), and the trailing 'cat' causes 'tee' to wait for the sub-shell to finish.